# Прошу объяснить мне как заполнить массив с помощью функции с++

Tags: c++, массивы, функции

Допустим, что я создал функцию, в которой цикл `for` заполняет массив пользовательским вводом до предела массива. Однако, позже я осознал, что созданному массиву в функции `main()` таким образом значения не передать. Поэтому у меня возник вопрос: **возможно ли заполнить массив через такую функцию?**

Comment: Почему это не передать? Приведите ваш код, где вы не можете передать значения

Comment: "значения в функцию не передать".  Каике значения?... Достаточно передать указатель на первый элемент массива и  размер.    И... функция не сущность, ее не создают, а определяют....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В C/C++ все массивы передаются в функции по указателю. Если Вы передаёте имя массива, то оно тоже понимается как указатель на его первый элемент. Все изменения массива, сделанные внутри функции, будут видны из вызывающей функции (в Вашем случае, видимо, это `main`).  Но тут есть тонкий момент - внутри функции определить размер переданного массива с помощью `sizeof` нельзя. Если применить `sizeof` к имени массива там, где массив объявлен (в `main`), будет возвращено количество байтов, занимаемых массивом (количество элементов в массиве: `sizeof(array_name)/sizeof(element_type)`). Если применить `sizeof` к имени массива, переданного внутрь функции, будет возвращён размер указателя в байтах, а не массива (зависит от разрядности Вашей ОС). Поэтому, если длина Вашего массива - не видимая глобально константа, её тоже надо передавать в функцию через параметр.

Comment: _"Если применить `sizeof` к имени массива там, где массив объявлен (в `main`), будет возвращено количество элементов в массиве."_ - а разве не количество **байт** занимаемых массивом?

Comment: @EOF Вы абсолютно правы, я подзабыл этот момент. Исправил ответ.